# Selecting a row in jTable generates error

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc

What i'm trying do here is that when i select a row in my table , after loading data , it should display the selected row's value in a text field (selectedRowTF). But as soon as i click on the jButton  the following error generates -

**java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1**

Since the error occurs even before the data is loaded , it leaves no chance for me to even select a row.

Also do you think I'm using the correct code to get the row's value?

[Stack Trace](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByWCrEzJsRmCMTdUYkZmOGNYNlU/view?usp=sharing)

```
DefaultTableModel model;
model=(DefaultTableModel)tbl.getModel();
try {
    Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");
    Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/divign","root","password");
    Statement stmt=con.createStatement();

    int row=tbl.getSelectedRow();
    String rowSelected=(tbl.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());

    String query="SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = '"+customerIdTF.getText()+"' ;";

    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
    if(rs.next()) {
        model.addRow (new Object[ ] {
            rs.getInt(1),rs.getString(2),rs.getString(3)
            });
        selectedRowTF.setText(""+rowSelected);  
    }
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    con.close();
}
catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.toString());
}
```

Comment: You should provide the stacktrace in your question, instead of linking to google docs. I can't access google docs from here, and it may not be available later to help someone else find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you just load your data, the `tbl.getSelectedRow()` returns `-1`.

After that you try to get the string value of the first column of your invalid row.

`String rowSelected=(tbl.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());`

=> that `getValueAt` leads to your exception.

Try the following:

```
String rowSelected = "";
if(row != -1)
{
    rowSelected = tbl.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
}
```

EDIT
As you said you just want to get the selected value, the position of your code is wrong.

You are trying to get the value of the selected row at the time you are loading your data. But at that time you don't select a row.
I think you need something like that (Value is printed out on a mouse click at the table):

```
tbl.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        int row = table.getSelectedRow();
        if (row > -1) {
            String value = (table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
            System.out.println("Value of row " + row + " col 0: '" + value + "'");
            selectedRowTF.setText(value);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid selection");
        }
    }
});
```

Or you can react on the selection with a button click:

```
private void btClickActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    int row = table.getSelectedRow();
    if (row > -1) {
        String value = (table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
        System.out.println("Value of row " + row + " col 0: '" + value + "'");
        selectedRowTF.setText(value);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid selection");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm typing '1', which is the first record in my table, in CustomerIdTF ...not just loading data...sorry if you meant something else please clarify it for me

Comment: ......as i said earlier the error occurs even before loading data that is as soon as i click on my button so  asking for  row is irrelevant.

Comment: Just wanted to ask for a stacktrace or something like that, so that i can help you finding your error... With the stacktrace you can determine the exact line where the error occurs, so it would be easy to find a solution for your problem

Comment: I have provided a link to it in my post.

Comment: Have you already tried my suggestion? The error occurs in the "getValueAt" function.
Please replace your " String rowSelected=(tbl.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());" with my solution and tell me if it worked.

Comment: Okay, the error is gone with the code you have provided but still if i select a row in the table nothing happens. I wanted to display the selected row's value in a text field (selectedRowTF)

Comment: @Yashw I edited my question, if it does help you, please accept it as answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Your situation is that when you called `tbl.getSelectedRow()`, it returned `-1`.  That is a sentinel value to indicate that no row is selected.  A row is selected when the mouse clicks on it, or when the keyboard moves the selection to it.  You will need to handle the situation when no row is selected.  I don't know your requirements and goals, so I can't advise on how to do that.  You can register a selection listener with the JTable if you want to be notified when the selection changes and react to it.  (See [`getSelectionModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectionModel--), [`addListSelectionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html#addListSelectionListener-javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener-), and [`ListSelectionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionListener.html))

You may get away without handling it if you didn't enable sorting or filtering on your JTable, however it is worth knowing that the row indexes in the *view* (`JTable`) are not the same indexes in the *model* (`DefaultTableModel`).  Use the [`convertRowIndexToModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel-int-) method to convert from the view's index (as reported by `getSelectedRow()`) to the model's index (required by `getValueAt()`).

The code you posted also contains SQL Injection issues.  I recommend researching that topic, and fix it using a [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and [`setString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString-int-java.lang.String-).